# How can I set up validation for a MudColorPicker within a MudForm in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, picker, mudblazor

I have a `Mudform` which contains a `MudColorPicker`. This `MudColorPicker` is a reuired part of the form and MUST be filled in by the user. I have tried different ways of setting up some validation but to no effect.

I've tried different variable binding and different validation forms. E.g

```
`  <MudForm @ref="@_form" Style="max-height: 800px; ">
<MudColorPicker @bind-Text="@BackgroundColour" Validation="@(new Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>(ColourPicker))" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
<MudColorPicker @bind-Text="@BackgroundColour" Required="true" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
<MudColorPicker @bind-Text="@BackgroundColour" Required="true" Validation="@(new Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>(ColourPicker))" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
<MudColorPicker @bind-Text="model.Colour" Validation="@(new Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>(ColourPicker))" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
<MudColorPicker @bind-Text="model.Colour" Required="true" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
<MudColorPicker @bind-Text="model.Colour" Required="true" Validation="@(new Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>(ColourPicker))" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
<MudColorPicker @bind-Value="model.Colour2" Validation="@(new Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>(ColourPicker))" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
<MudColorPicker @bind-Value="model.Colour2" Required="true" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
<MudColorPicker @bind-Value="model.Colour2" Required="true" Validation="@(new Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>(ColourPicker))" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
```

```
@code {
    public MudForm _form { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColour { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    Category model = new Category();

    public class Category
    {
        [Required]
        public string Colour { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public MudColor Colour2 { get; set; }
    }


    private IEnumerable<string> ColourPicker(string colour)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(colour))
        {
            yield return "Background colour is required!";
            yield break;
        }
    }
}`
```

Just tried:

```
 <MudColorPicker @bind-Value="model.Colour2" ErrorText="Colour Required" Required="true" Validation="@mudColourValidator.Validation" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
            <MudColorPicker @bind-Value="model.Colour2" ErrorText="Colour Required" Required="false" Validation="@mudColourValidator.Validation" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />
            <MudColorPicker @bind-Value="model.Colour2" ErrorText="Colour Required" Validation="@mudColourValidator.Validation" ColorPickerView="ColorPickerView.GridCompact" />


@code{
 FluentValueValidator<MudColor> mudColourValidator = new FluentValueValidator<MudColor>(x => x.NotEmpty());
}
```